# Что означает "оператор auto?"

Tags: c++, операторы

```
template <typename T>
struct A {
    operator auto() {
        return T{};
    }
};
```

Что означает "оператор auto"? В чём его отличие от `explicit operator auto()`? Когда они применяются?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// 1
struct widget {
    operator int() { return 10; }
};

// 2
struct widget2 {
    operator auto() { return std::string{"hello"}; }
};

// 3
struct widget3 {
    explicit operator int() { return 10; }
};

// пример из вопроса
template <typename T>
struct A {
    // метод для преобразования объектов типа A<T>
    // в тип T (выведено)
    operator auto() {
        return T{};
    }
};    

int main()
{
    widget w;
    int wint = w; // ok

    widget2 w2;
    std::string wstr = w2; // ok

    widget3 w3;
    int w3int = w3; // error
    int w3inte = static_cast<int>(w3); // ok

    A<std::string> as;
    std::string asstr = as; // ok
    int asint = as; // error
}
```

1. [Определенные пользователем преобразования](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). Есть возможность определить метод преобразования пользовательского типа в другой тип.
2. [Вывод типа с помощью auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). Как к любой другой функции, `auto` применим и к преобразователям.
3. [Explicit-спецификатор](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit). (для функций преобразования) указывает копилятору, что функцию преобразования не нужно рассматривать при неявных приведениях типа.

---

Начиная со стандарта C++14, ключевое слово `auto` можно использовать для типа возвращаемого значения функции, указывая, что тип возвращаемого значения должен быть выведен. Вместе с этим, `auto` может быть использован в операторах преобразования (также начиная с C++14).

Существует одно исключение, `auto` нельзя использовать в шаблонных операторах преобразования. `template <typename U> operator auto() { return 1; }` - не будет компилироваться.

В примере из вопроса `operator auto() { return T{}; }`. Оператор преобразования не является шаблонным, требования к выведению типов соблюдены (все `return`-ы имеют одинаковый тип) - можно выводить тип. Тип будет выведен как `T` и данный оператор преобразования можно рассматривать как `operator T{ return T{}; }`

Comment: Не могли бы вы дополнить ответ тем, почему можно использовать auto в данном контексте? Ссылки - это, конечно, хорошо, но желательно привести цитаты в самом ответе

Comment: @cppquestions, обновил